# obeyspaces but not at end of line

Tags: spacing

I have some code that code as soon as it overflows a line it should (indented) continue on the next line. This functions, but the problem I get is that multiple spaces are "joined" to 1 space, this is unwanted. When I use now either `\obeyspaces` or `\` the continuation is done after a word completion.
I would like to have that in case a word go beyond the line width it will go to the next line, so in that case the spaces are the end of the line "are preserved but not shown".

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{hanging}

    \newlength{\CodeWidth}
    \newcommand\CodeLine[1]{\hangpara{\CodeWidth}{1}{#1}\par}

    \newenvironment{Code}{%
      \par%
      \scriptsize%
      \normalfont\ttfamily%
      \settowidth{\CodeWidth}{000000}%
      \setlength{\parskip}{0ex plus 0ex minus 0ex}%
      \obeyspaces%
    }{%
      \normalsize%
      \normalfont%
    }

    \begin{document}

    \begin{Code}
    \CodeLine{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam commodo mattis orci, id gravida leo dignissim condimentum. Aliquam porta est ac placerat laoreet. Nam faucibus tincidunt augue eget efficitur. Donec faucibus, magna vitae tempor cursus, nulla felis hendrerit dolor, ut sollicitudin erat libero vel nisl. Nulla volutpat lacinia interdum. Vivamus sodales ullamcorper vulputate. Sed nulla metus, tincidunt convallis purus vel, sagittis dignissim arcu. Aliquam vitae augue quis magna luctus cursus nec at ex. Vestibulum porttitor neque purus, id imperdiet ante cursus quis. Aenean vel nunc volutpat, suscipit nisi quis, faucibus arcu. Aliquam vel enim venenatis nisl malesuada condimentum. Cras vel sollicitudin enim. Nulla sagittis et nunc sit amet sagittis. Aliquam nibh est, semper vel quam a, aliquet scelerisque metus. Sed laoreet cursus urna, eget euismod massa vehicula eget. }
    \CodeLine{Lorem        ipsum        dolor        sit        amet,        consectetur        adipiscing        elit.        Etiam        commodo        mattis        orci,        id        gravida        leo        dignissim        condimentum.        Aliquam        porta        est        ac        placerat        laoreet.        Nam        faucibus        tincidunt        augue        eget        efficitur.        Donec        faucibus,        magna        vitae        tempor        cursus,        nulla        felis        hendrerit        dolor,        ut        sollicitudin        erat        libero        vel        nisl.        Nulla        volutpat        lacinia        interdum.        Vivamus        sodales        ullamcorper        vulputate.        Sed        nulla        metus,        tincidunt        convallis        purus        vel,        sagittis        dignissim        arcu.        Aliquam        vitae        augue        quis        magna        luctus        cursus        nec        at        ex.        Vestibulum        porttitor        neque        purus,        id        imperdiet        ante        cursus        quis.        Aenean        vel        nunc        volutpat,        suscipit        nisi        quis,        faucibus        arcu.        Aliquam        vel        enim        venenatis        nisl        malesuada        condimentum.        Cras        vel        sollicitudin        enim.        Nulla        sagittis        et        nunc        sit        amet        sagittis.        Aliquam        nibh        est,        semper        vel        quam        a,        aliquet        scelerisque        metus.        Sed        laoreet        cursus        urna,        eget        euismod        massa        vehicula        eget.        }
    \end{Code}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

In this example the words 'elit' should go to the next line(, moving this word to the next line would influence the rest of the text and thus the words to be moved).

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need the `\normalsize\normalfont` at the end of the environment. The grouping level created by `\newenvironment` restores the font at the `\end{Code}`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks, I thought so but it is similar is in the package that generates the (sty) file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code below there is room for variation. The commented out version is the one giving the image so that spaces are visible.

Sorry for background colors, I took 3 times the screen shot with this Ubuntu 16.04 capture and it has this artefact.

After first post I read more closely both question and original code, so this might fit better the bill.

In this code, comment out line with `\char32` and uncomment the other to get spaces, not visible spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hanging}

\newlength{\CodeWidth}
\newcommand\CodeLine[1]{\hangpara{\CodeWidth}{1}{#1}\par}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\NiceSpace{%
  \discretionary{\char32}{}{\char32}%
%  \discretionary{\kern\fontdimen2\font}{}{\kern\fontdimen2\font}%
}%
\makeatother

\newenvironment{Code}{%
  \par
  \scriptsize
  \normalfont\ttfamily
  \rightskip0pt plus 1fil
  \settowidth{\CodeWidth}{000000}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0ex plus 0ex minus 0ex}%
  {\lccode`~32 \lowercase{\global\let~}\NiceSpace}\obeyspaces%
}{%
%  \normalsize%
%  \normalfont%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{Code}
\CodeLine{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam commodo mattis orci, id gravida leo dignissim condimentum. Aliquam porta est ac placerat laoreet. Nam faucibus tincidunt augue eget efficitur. Donec faucibus, magna vitae tempor cursus, nulla felis hendrerit dolor, ut sollicitudin erat libero vel nisl. Nulla volutpat lacinia interdum. Vivamus sodales ullamcorper vulputate. Sed nulla metus, tincidunt convallis purus vel, sagittis dignissim arcu. Aliquam vitae augue quis magna luctus cursus nec at ex. Vestibulum porttitor neque purus, id imperdiet ante cursus quis. Aenean vel nunc volutpat, suscipit nisi quis, faucibus arcu. Aliquam vel enim venenatis nisl malesuada condimentum. Cras vel sollicitudin enim. Nulla sagittis et nunc sit amet sagittis. Aliquam nibh est, semper vel quam a, aliquet scelerisque metus. Sed laoreet cursus urna, eget euismod massa vehicula eget. }

\noindent{}X\dotfill{}X

\CodeLine{Lorem        ipsum        dolor        sit        amet,        consectetur        adipiscing        elit.        Etiam        commodo        mattis        orci,        id        gravida        leo        dignissim        condimentum.        Aliquam        porta        est        ac        placerat        laoreet.        Nam        faucibus        tincidunt        augue        eget        efficitur.        Donec        faucibus,        magna        vitae        tempor        cursus,        nulla        felis        hendrerit        dolor,        ut        sollicitudin        erat        libero        vel        nisl.        Nulla        volutpat        lacinia        interdum.        Vivamus        sodales        ullamcorper        vulputate.        Sed        nulla        metus,        tincidunt        convallis        purus        vel,        sagittis        dignissim        arcu.        Aliquam        vitae        augue        quis        magna        luctus        cursus        nec        at        ex.        Vestibulum        porttitor        neque        purus,        id        imperdiet        ante        cursus        quis.        Aenean        vel        nunc        volutpat,        suscipit        nisi        quis,        faucibus        arcu.        Aliquam        vel        enim        venenatis        nisl        malesuada        condimentum.        Cras        vel        sollicitudin        enim.        Nulla        sagittis        et        nunc        sit        amet        sagittis.        Aliquam        nibh        est,        semper        vel        quam        a,        aliquet        scelerisque        metus.        Sed        laoreet        cursus        urna,        eget        euismod        massa        vehicula        eget.        }
\end{Code}

\hrule height 3pt
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The solution looks quite good to me.  I'll wait a little bit for even better answers before accepting this answer as best answer.

Comment: I have read your question more closely and updated my answer. Now whole words will move to next line if they don't fit. But I see I need to improve something. Problem is I started from some code of mine doing something altogether different..

Comment: ok, I have done my final edit... did I understand right you don't want words cut in two? else another approach is needed.

Comment: Indeed I don't want the words to be cut in two (as it is source code that is pronted, for the example I used the Lorem version).