# Problem with \discretionary inside a longtable (tabu) cell

Tags: tables, longtable, tabu, longtabu

I'm working on embedding code into the code documentation and here it is also necessary to have code in table cells. I have the following (stripped down ) code (based on the excellent answer from @jfbu [obeyspaces but not at end of line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426984/obeyspaces-but-not-at-end-of-line/426999#426999)):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{hanging}

\newenvironment{MyParams}[2][]{%
    \tabulinesep=1mm%
    \par%
    \begin{longtabu*}spread 0pt [l]{|X[-1,l]|X[-1,l]|}
}{%
    \end{longtabu*}%
    \vspace{6pt}%
}

\newlength{\MyCodeWidth}
\newcommand\NiceSpace{%
     \discretionary{}{\kern\fontdimen2\font}{\kern\fontdimen2\font}%
}

\newcommand\MyCodeLine[1]{\hangpara{\MyCodeWidth}{1}{#1}\par}

\newenvironment{MyCode}{%
  \par%
  \rightskip0pt plus 1fil%
  \settowidth{\MyCodeWidth}{000000}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0ex plus 0ex minus 0ex}%
  {\lccode`~32 \lowercase{\global\let~}\NiceSpace}\obeyspaces%
}{%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{MyParams}{Parameters}
\begin{MyCode}
\MyCodeLine{Lorem    ipsum    dolor    sit    amet,    consectetur    adipiscing    elit.    Etiam    commodo    mattis    orci,    id    gravida    leo    dignissim    condimentum.}
\end{MyCode}
\end{MyParams}

\end{document}
```

And now I get the error message:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \discretionary
l.38 \end{MyParams}
```

So I apparently missed something and still struggling ..., but I don't have an idea where to look. In case of problems between `tabu` and `verbatim` a message was given in the `tabu` manual but here / now I cannot find anything.

Comment: On a lot of places it is suggested to remove the `.aux` file, but this didn't help.